# Arduino Disconnects after router password changes

Tags: ethernet, wifi

I am working with arduino Uno R3 connected with EPS8266(http://www.amazon.in/ESP8266-Serial-Wireless-Transceiver-Module/dp/B00O34AGSU?tag=googinhydr18418-21&tag=googinkenshoo-21&ascsubtag=858e5035-7713-403a-942e-487a0fe24800). After router password is changed, it should be re programmed with new password. Is there any another way not to do so repeatedly. I managed 2 SSID for router which one have always unique password. But I think this is not a solution. Is there any technique or idea that says only for particular mac address, the SSID will be opened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Routers have multiple "passwords".  I assume you are talking about your wireless encryption key (i.e. WPA/WPA2 key).  When the encryption key is changed, you are correct: you have to re-program the ESP8266 with the new key, because it can't learn this information on its own.  If this key were broadcast, then your network would not be secure as everyone would be informed of the encryption key.

Why is the key changing?  Is there really a need to change the encryption key often?

MAC addresses can be spoofed, so permitting a specific MAC address to "always connect" is not secure.

Comment: Thanks for ur valuable reply.. I am making a very secure wifi protocol that has a function to allow network for particular mac address. Because the device in which it is gonna be loaded will not be touch for next 5 years. In between if router changes may occur than this problem may arise.